# Create grouping variable based on the occurrences of NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sequence

I have a dataframe `df` that contains a column `x`:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1))
```

Those `1`'s are just placeholders to represent any non-missing numeric values. I want to create another column `y` by which `df` is able to grouped.

```r
   x  y
1  1  1
2  1  1
3 NA  2
4  1  2
5  1  2
6 NA  3
7 NA  3
8  1  3
9  1  3
```

The logic is that when a `NA` is encountered, add 1 to the previous `y`. However, if the `NA`'s are in series, the logic only applies on the first occurrence, so the values of `y` since the 6th row are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` after comparing the current and the previous by invoking `lag`:

```
df %>%
   mutate(grp = cumsum(is.na(x) & !is.na(lag(x))) + 1)

   x grp
1  1   1
2  1   1
3 NA   2
4  1   2
5  1   2
6 NA   3
7 NA   3
8  1   3
9  1   3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using `diff` with `cumsum()`

```
library(dplyr) 

df %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(c(0, diff(!is.na(x))) != 0 & !is.na(x))+1)

   x grp
1  1   1
2  1   1
3 NA   1
4  1   2
5  1   2
6 NA   2
7 NA   2
8  1   3
9  1   3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
   mutate(grp = dense_rank(x * consecutive_id(x)))%>%
   fill(grp, .direction = 'up')

   x grp
1  1   1
2  1   1
3 NA   2
4  1   2
5  1   2
6 NA   3
7 NA   3
8 NA   3
9  1   3
```

Comment: This method may not work for me because I have said those 1's can be any non-missing numeric values. But your first answer works perfectly. Thanks!